# How do I motivate myself?

Tags: professionalism

I'm a 22-year old PHP Web Developer with 3 years experience. I'm from Pakistan and working in UAE as PHP Developer. Nowadays I have no challenge-able tasks. Being a developer I love to develop something new, unique and innovative, but I'm doing nothing since last month except learning Laravel.

My manager gives me tasks like adding a border bottom, adding an input field etc. My boss screamed at me twice when he found a minor bug in the website like an alignment issue. I defended myself saying that I'm a developer not a designer, but his reply was that *If someone doesn't take care of their responsibilities then lay them off.*

Everyday I'm checking our in-house website more than a 100 times. I'm very worried about what will be happen if something is wrong, even with the server. Sometimes I can't sleep properly due to this kind of headache. However everything is fine, I'm just scared.

Since they are not technical, when issues come up they always blame developers.

I worked on a few CMSs and frameworks like Opencart, WordPress, Codeignitor, Smarty and some custom made PHP code. I want to become a full stack developer and for this I'm learning about programming like Laravel, Symfony3 and other new libraries and frameworks. But I believe that the best way of learning is to actually develop something rather than reading about syntax and functions.

I'm very demotivated and don't know what I should do. Whenever someone knows I'm a Web Application Developer (s)he says *you're lucky and you are in good field*. I know this is a good field for those whose are experts, but that's  not like me (Just aligning things the entire day).

I'm writing here because I believe in this community there are lot of experienced developers and experts. Please guide me what should I do in this situation and how to become a full stack developer, so that I can join a good and expert team in the future.

Comment: You do the hard, boring, pedantic work and gain experience like most others.

Comment: `I believe that the best way of learning is to actually develop something` Right. And of course you can do so, outside of work. Then, someday, you can use the experience to get a better salary.

Comment: @deviantfan I appreciate your comment

Comment: Even if you're not experts, finding another job is pretty easy in web development. If this job is no more a fit for you, move on. And by the way changing job is always the best way to have a better salary.

Comment: @Walfrat, I think being an Pakistani expat in Dubai might make looking for a new job harder (and the consequences of being fired more dire) - things like visa and working permits are usually tied to having a position, or even to a specific employer.

Comment: @EikePierstorff Yes this is the reason

Comment: "he found a minor bug in the website like an alignment issue. I defended myself saying that I'm a developer not a designer" - hmm. Was this really a design issue or a development issue? Is there actually a designer? Or is that you?

Comment: "I'm very demotivated and don't know what I should do. " - is there a reason why you don't find yourself a job more aligned with what you want to do, then quit this one? Seems like the obvious choice to me.

Comment: Just find a new job

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> **I'm a 22-year old PHP Web Developer with 3 years experience. I'm from**
>
> **Pakistan and working in UAE as PHP Developer.**

That's quite a good thing that you have 3 years of experience at this age.

> **but I'm doing nothing since last month except learning Laravel.**

You "are" doing something i.e. learning a new technology rather than sitting idle.

> **Everyday I'm checking our in-house website more than a 100 times.**

You don't need to keep rechecking your work. Be confident with what you do.

> **Since they are not technical, when issues come up they always blame**
>
> **developers.**

This is what most of them do. So, don't worry just focus on your work.

> **I'm very demotivated and don't know what I should do.**

Sometimes, the little things you do can help you do wonders. Remember, you are a sculptor of your own sculpture. So, just focus on whatever work you have been assigned and keep evolving your self by doing what you do i.e.e Learn new technologies. And off course, keep seeking for better opportunities.

Do remember to clear your responsibilities while landing into a new job else you might be stuck again in a similar position.

Comment: He seams to be going back "100 times" because his manager told him "mistake makers go unemployed in here" after being scolded by him ..

Comment: Question is about getting motivated. Motivation comes in absense of fear. And I believe, confidence overcomes fear.

Comment: @ИвоНедев Yes, Almost same thing happened

Comment: Above points are enough for motivation specially top one and second last. +1

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to a fairly common misinterpretation of agile development. Where you get bite sized chunks of work from a task list and very seldom get to do something "huge" or "important". I call this factory style - battery hen, coding monkey - development, and I really dislike it.

Unfortunately more companies seem to be adopting this style of development.

Your only hope towards some sanity is to be the team lead for a while and then elevate beyond this to product owner or where you're at least involved in the architecture.

Also since you're from Pakistan working in Dubai must suck. That whole city, even the whole UAE seems kind of racist, and I'm sure you're getting paid less because you're from Pakistan. Consider immigrating to the UK or some other fair company where you're not discriminated against because of race - just saying.

Answer (score -4):

Whenever I have a need to motivate myself to do something, I remember the following motivator.

[image]

Sadly, it is in Russian, but here is a very very rough translation. This type of motivation does not work for everyone, but it works perfectly for me.

> How to motivate yourself?
>
> You should not, stay in shit.